# Is a Sodium Chlorite Product Safe for Car Odor-Removal?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, water

I would like to ask the science community's opinion about the safety of sodium chlorite for use as an odor-eliminator in an automobile's interior.
While the ingredient in the product is sodium chlorite the technology listed is ClO2 (chlorine dioxide).
The product is Auto Shocker.  https://www.autoshocker.com/
It involves a tea bag like pouch of sodium chlorite reacting with water to form a gas that eliminates odors in a car:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EaZaPbth6k&t=4s

Does the gas turn into harmless saline in time?
Should there be any concern with reactions with other chemicals or materials present in a car?

Here is the msds for the product: https://www.autoshocker.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/msds.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't want it lying around. It's practically a bleach and could be dangerous if used improperly.

Comment: See fraud indictment for ClO2: https://arstechnica.com/health/2023/07/church-of-bleach-family-guilty-on-all-counts-plans-to-appeal/

Answer (score 1):

Though personal medical questions are off-topic, here's a quote from a [$\ce{ClO2}$ Safety Data Sheet](https://ecosensecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/ClorDiSys-SDS-Chlorine-Dioxide-Gas.pdf), as opposed to that of the product, which you cite.

> **Severe respiratory irritant**. May cause bronchospasm and pulmonary
> edema, which may be delayed in onset. **May also cause severe headaches**.
> **All symptoms may be delayed and long lasting**. Long term exposure may
> cause chronic bronchitis.  May be harmful if absorbed through skin.
>
> Exposure Limits: ACGIH 1992-93: TWA 0.1 ppm, STEL 0.3 ppm (0.9 mg/m3).

That said, how much $\ce{ClO2}$ is released by that product is another question. If it's strong enough to oxidize odoriferous substances, is it safe, and if it's safe, could it possibly do the job?